# Extracting Metadata in Google Sheets ImportXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, metadata, google-sheets-formula

Is it still possible to extract metadata like price from a site using ImportXML in Google Sheets?

I have tried multiple different variations on the following page without success: https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646/Office-Depot-White-Copy-Paper-Letter/

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646/Office-Depot-White-Copy-Paper-Letter/","//*[contains(@itemprop,'price')]/@content")
```

---

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/273646/Office-Depot-White-Copy-Paper-Letter/","//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")
```

I should be able to use this formula to return "58.99", but I continuously receive an NA error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OfficeDepot seems to block the requests from GoogleSheets.
Some clues :

- Get the price directly from the .json (we can't use `ImportJSON` script to load this directly in Sheets since requests are blocked). Change the product id in the url accordingly :

  https://www.officedepot.com/mobile/getAjaxPriceListFromService.do?items=273646&mapBySkuId=true&includeOos=true
- Another option could be to use [SerpAPI](https://serpapi.com/)(commercial)+ImportJSON to fetch the product price from GoogleShooping.
- Or you can use the GoogleSearch API(free)+`ImportJson`. Output :

[image]

You need an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=fr) and an [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/ae64c908b82cc8cf8840e176930ad937883fbe37/ImportJSON.gs) script (credits to Brad Jasper) to do this. Once you have installed the script and activated your API key, [add a search engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/all). In the settings, you have to define the target website.

[image]

Copy somewhere your search engine id (cx=XXXXXXXXXX). Once this is done and assuming you have the urls in column A, you can paste in cell B2 :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2;"products\/(\d+)")
```

This is for extracting the product id.

In cell C2, you can paste :

```
="https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cx={yoursearchengineID}&key={yourAPIkey}&num=1&fields=items(pagemap(offer(price)))&q="&B2
```

We construct the request for the API. You need to add your API key and your search engine id in this formula.

In cell D2, you can paste :

```
=QUERY(ImportJSON(C2);"SELECT Col1 label Col1''";1)
```

This for importing the .json result and cleaning it a bit.

Notes : this method could fail with some products (the new ones). I'm based in Europe. So ";" in the formulas should be replaced with ",".

Comment: OK, that makes sense! I was using this site as an example since it previously worked. They probably changed it for that exact reason. I very much appreciate the workaround solution even more!